# Using special characters as CASE keys in typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions, powermail

I'm trying to send a mail via the powermail extension to different receivers, depending on the value a user has selected in a form dropdown. This practice of *dynamic receivers* is described in the [powermail documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/5.5.0/ForAdministrators/BestPractice/DynamicReceiver/). Basically:

```
receivers1.email = CASE
receivers1.email {

    key.data = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|field|receiver

    1 = TEXT
    1.value = receivera@domain.org

    default = TEXT
    default.value = receiverb@domain.org
}
```

Now I'm facing the following problem: my values for "receiver" are not numeric (as in the example), but text values from a dropdown. Some of them contain spaces, some of them contain umlauts (öäüß). If I try to add …

```
Not wörking = TEXT
Not wörking.value = anotheremail@nowhere.org
```

Typo3 will complain and not update anything. (*Bad property!
You must enter a property with characters a-z, A-Z and 0-9, no spaces!Nothing was updated!*)

I tried simply 'escaping' the forbidden characters with a backslash, not working. Had an idea of converting the `key.data` via `stdWrap rawUrlEncode`, but did not work either. Google came up [with this solution](https://gist.github.com/dandjelkovic/2710837), but I don't understand what's going on and could not use it successfully.

How can I get around this? Thanks a lot for any kind of hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pretty like your rawUrlEncode solution. Can you provide us your solution of it here? According to this [online converter](https://de.functions-online.com/rawurlencode.html) the result should be something like:

```
key.data = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|field|receiver
key.stdWrap.rawUrlEncode = 1

Not%20w%C3%B6rking = TEXT
Not%20w%C3%B6rking.value = anotheremail@nowhere.org
```

Maybe for each CASE some signs like "%" are not allowed. In that case you maybe refer to the "replacement" function. https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/8.7/Functions/Replacement/Index.html#replacement

```
key.data = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|field|receiver
key.stdWrap.replacement {
  10 {
      search.char = 32
      replace = _
  }
  // Add umlauts and other signs!
}

Not_wörking = TEXT
Not_wörking.value = anotheremail@nowhere.org
```

Comment: Yes you're right, the '%' are not allowed either. I'll give your `replacement` method a try, sure looks good!