# Typo3 9.5 Powermail CASE with german "umlaut"

Tags: typoscript, typo3-9.x, powermail

I found a nice TypoScript code snippet to use different Text based on which option choosed in a webform:
https://www.typo3.net/forum/thematik/zeige/thema/111899/

```
lib.salutation = CASE
lib.salutation {
    
    key.field = 0   
 
    Herr = TEXT
    Herr.value = Sehr geehrter Herr
    Herr.noTrimWrap = || |
 
    Frau = TEXT
    Frau.value = Sehr geehrte Frau
    Frau.noTrimWrap = || |
}
```

But i need to use an option called "Daten ändern". But this will obiously not work:

```
Daten ändern = TEXT
Daten ändern.value = Daten ändern bla bla
Daten ändern.noTrimWrap = || |
```

How can i use "Daten ändern" with the code above?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello @user3759978, there is an alternate solution explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51498341/using-special-characters-as-case-keys-in-typoscript

Comment: Yes! This was a good hint! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

With the hint from [Anu Bhuvanendran Nair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5663872/anu-bhuvanendran-nair)

I could edit my code to:

```
key.stdWrap.replacement {
  10 {
      search.char = 32
      replace = _
  }
  20 {
      search = ä
      replace = ae
  }
Daten_aendern = TEXT
Daten_aendern.value = Daten ändern bla bla
Daten_aendern.noTrimWrap = || |
```

Wich works fine